# Database Normalization

Tags: database, normalization

how to normalize a table from a relational schema upto BCNF. Can someone please explain the normalization of below relational schema upto BCNF with details.

```
info(id, companyName, contactName, contactTitle, address, city, postalCode, country, phone, fax, email, website)
```

Comment: All of those seem specific to the subject of a company. I don't see much normalization happening beyond this

Comment: The question does not make sense without information about you model and constraints. I can't tell whether the table is in `BCNF` or not because I can't tell which attributes are functionally dependent on each other.

Comment: To make it a bit more blunt: do you have multiple contacts per company?  Is the address/city/zip/etc for the contact or for the company?  Is the email for the company or the contact?  Is the website for the company or the contact?  Also, this seems pretty generic, is this homework?

Comment: This looks like homework for some database theory course where you get to learn 2NF 3NF BCNF 4NF etc. But it's okay since chances are you will only remember up to 3NF as used in practice

Answer (score 3):

You can only do normalization when you have defined functional dependencies. Give me a set of functional dependencies (e.g., id uniquely determines companyName, postalCode uniquely determines Country, etc.) and we can talk about normalization.

Let me state this again: no rational human being can attempt to answer your question without your giving us the functional dependencies. If you want help coming up with a set of meaningful functional dependencies for this schema, we can wildly hypothesize as to what rules your data should follow, but ultimately it's up to you to tell us what your business rules are.

That being said: once you have the functional dependencies, getting the relation in BCNF is fairly straightforward. Your relation is in BCNF iff the left side of every functional dependency is a superkey. If you have a functional dependency that violates this, simply spin that off as a new relation. Then you'll transform your non-BCNF relation into a set of relations which are either in BCNF or not; if so, stop; otherwise, continue. Note that this process eventually terminates because relations with two columns are trivially in BCNF.

Answer (score -3):

Boyce Codd normal form just means that you are in 3rd normal form with the addition that foreign keys are linked between tables, without the ability for other columns to cause inconsistencies.  I like the example in the link below showing a table describing "Shop Near Person".  It has a primary key to a person, a primary key to a shop, then another field showing the type of shop.  This violates BCNF because the "shop type" field may not be consistent which the shop's primary key.

BCNF is explained decently here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boyce%E2%80%93Codd_normal_form

I'm making some assumptions, but here is how I would split the fields.  Some people like to go further and split addresses out, but I feel that is normalizing beyond the 3rd form.  I noticed you had a country field, so I also split the phone fields up for international dialing, as the number will change depending on which country you are calling from and to.

### Companies

company_id, companyName, address, city, state, postalCode, country_id, phoneCountryCode, phoneAreaCode, phoneVoiceNumber, phoneExtension, phoneFaxNumber

### Contacts

contact_id, company_id, contactName, contactTitle, contactEmail

### Countries

country_id, countryName

Comment: Normalizing has absolutely nothing to do with id numbers, and it has absolutely nothing to do with breaking a phone number into pieces.

Comment: But the physical act of performing the actual normalization is ids.  Once you have sectioned out the repeating parts you want to isolate, you split them using primary/foreign keys.  I realize that splitting a phone number is not normalization, I added that as a courtesy.

Comment: No, the physical act of normalizing a table still doesn't have anything to do with id numbers. But that *is* a common misconception. ID numbers are mostly used either to improve join performance or to identify entities that lack a usable, natural identifier. Neither of those things has to do with normalization. (There's no such thing as "ID number normal form", and none of the normal forms include the criterion, "Add an ID number if one doesn't already exist.")

Comment: I will concede to your statement that the act of determining the entities that you normalize have nothing to with id fields.  But since you brought up this conversation about id's, you apparently thought my answer was stating that the act of normalization is nothing but primary keys.  How did you come to that conclusion?  The person asking the question wanted to know how to normalize a list of fields using BCNF, and I gave an explanation of BCNF along with an example of entities, attributes, and their relationships.

Comment: You said, "you apparently thought my answer was stating that the act of normalization is nothing but primary keys". No, I just observed that you'd introduced two ID numbers and some other attributes that didn't exist in the original table, and that you left at least one out. Normalization doesn't involve introducing new columns or eliminating old columns.

Comment: I was answering your original statement when I said that.  I'm afraid I have to disagree with you on adding id's. If you are normalizing a table, unless you are using an existing column as a primary key, such as a social security number, you must add primary keys in order to make normalization possible, less you cannot link to a foreign entity.

Comment: If you're doing normalization, you *will* be using existing columns by definition. Normalization through BCNF involves identifying functional dependencies (FDs) between existing columns; FDs identify columns to be used as primary keys. Read carefully the Wikipedia article at the link you provided. No ID numbers.

Comment: ID numbers are candidate keys. They satisfy the definition you keep pointing out. How would you have normalized the example in this question without using an id, and without using the obvious trivial superkey?

Comment: Normalization doesn't introduce columns that weren't in the original table. Normalization doesn't break existing columns into pieces.

Comment: You dodged my question, but I will answer your two statements.  One, there is not a rule in normalization that states you cannot introduce a better candidate key column if a sufficient one does not exist.  Two, when you say "breaking existing columns into pieces", are you still referring to me splitting the phone number field?  I stated clearly that the phone number was not normalization.  I did that as a courtesy.  Now let me ask my question again.  How would you have answered fkrafi's question above, without using an id, and without using the obvious trivial superkey.

Comment: "One, there is not a rule in normalization that states you cannot introduce a better candidate key column" Well, yes, there *is* such a rule. It's in the definition of *projection*, which is the operator for decomposition. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projection_(relational_algebra) says "In practical terms, it can be roughly thought of as picking a sub-set of all available columns."

Comment: Why not add a candidate key column to all available columns, and include that in your projection set. The example shown on wikipedia used first name/age. Works for an example, but is hardly a good candidate key in the real world.  I would use person_id/age.

Comment: Answered at least 5 times already. Better column names are a good idea, but better column names don't have anything to do with normalization either. Not every idea has to do with normalization.